# imageView android not recognized error

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am wondering why image view in java class pots error
like `ImageView smtin;`
And there's error.
It dont recognize it like class...

My project code is:

```
    package com.klemenjezakon.koceSLO;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

ImageView slika;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        koca podatki=(koca)i.getSerializableExtra("koca");


        setContentView(R.layout.koca);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put inside your class. So instead of:

```
ImageView slika;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

it have to be:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView slika;
```